# Determine the order of the permutation (134)(347)(485) Note: The above product is not disjoint

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

This is my claim I was wondering if anybody can check it. Your time is greatly appreatiated.

[image]

Comment: Why make so much work of it? Why not juist say $(1\ 3\ 4)(3\ 4 7)(4\ 8\ 5)=(1\ 3)(4\ 8\ 5\ 7)$ in **disjoint** cycle form. Since $(1\ 3)$ has order $2$ and $(4\ 8\ 5\ 7)$ has order $4$, the product of those two **disjoint** permutations has order $\operatorname{LCM}(2,4)=4$?